# Setting Value From Offset and Calling Function from a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops, offset

I have to be close on this but I have something coded incorrectly here. Below is my loop sub with the title of my function because I think my syntax is off in both spots because i get the error that my argument is incorrect.

I run a similar loop where I only need to pass the value in the loop, but the offset and multiple values being passed to the function has me stuck here.

```
Public Sub ProduceReports()
    Dim a As Range
    Dim StartingWS As Worksheet
    Dim ClientFolder As String
    Dim ExportFile As String
    Dim PreparedDate As String
    Dim Exports As String
    Dim AccountNumber As String
    Set StartingWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Starting Page")
    
    '************* This code creates the folder and sets the export path for the individual spreadsheets**********
    
    ClientFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Starting Page").Cells(I10).Value
    PreparedDate = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm")
    MkDir "P:\Class Actions\" & ClientFolder
    ExportFile = "P:\Class Actions\" & ClientFolder & " - " & PreparedDate
    Exports = ExportFile


Worksheets("Standby").Visible = True
Sheets("Standby").Activate

    '************* This is the loop to check the cells and set the offset value as the account number**********
        
        
    For Each a In StartingWS.Range("G9:G29").Cells
        If a.Value = Eligible Then
        AccountNumber = a.Offset(0, -1).Value
        PrepareClassSheets (AccountNumber.Value,Exports.Value)
        
                        End If
    Next a
    
     
Sheets("Starting Page").Activate
Worksheets("Standby").Visible = False

CompleteMessage = MsgBox("Class Action Data for" & " " & ClientFolder & " " & "has been prepared.", , "Bear has completed his tasks.")
MsgBox (CompleteMessage)
     
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ExportFile, vbNormalFocus)
    
End Sub


Function PrepareClassSheets(AccountNumber As String, Exports As String)
```

Comment: `PrepareClassSheets (AccountNumber, Exports)` both `AccountNumber` and `Exports` are already strings

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it is still saying it expects an "=".  Thoughts?

Comment: `PrepareClassSheets  AccountNumber, Exports ` you don't need parentheses here.  You're calling a Function, but not capturing the return value.

Comment: `ClientFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Starting Page").Range("I10").Value`